# Passing flags to script in npm command

Tags: node.js, npm, cypress, npm-scripts, create-react-native-app

I am using create-react-app for my building my application and I am using cypress for automation.

```
    "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "cy:run": "cypress run ,
    "cypress:all": "start-server-and-test start http-get://localhost:3000 cy:run"
}
```

In order to run the test, firstly I need to boot up my application using `npm start` and then I can run command `npm run cy:run -- --record --key <record-key>`.

Instead what I am doing is run the command `npm run cypress:all` which will call `npm start` and once server is up and running it runs tests on it.
But how do I pass the record flag for this command? `npm run cypress:all -- --record <record-key>` doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

The [start-server-and-test docs](https://github.com/bahmutov/start-server-and-test#commands) says

> In addition to using NPM script names, you can pass entire commands (surround them with quotes so it is still a single string) that will be executed "as is". For example, to start globally installed http-server before running and recording Cypress.io tests you can use
>   `start-server-and-test 'http-server -c-1 --silent' 8000 './node_modules/.bin/cypress run --record'`

Comment: './node_modules/.bin/cypress run. I find it untidy. That's why I'd like to have a npm script